# Reheating Dr. Green Agent X

Tags: recreational-drugs, marijuana, urine-test

I have purchased the product [Dr. Green Agent X](http://www.drgreens.com/Dr-Greens-Agent-X-Fake-Pee-Premixed).
How many times I can put the un-opened product in the microwave before it becomes unusable?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the product?

Comment: @Narusan http://www.drgreens.com/Dr-Greens-Agent-X-Fake-Pee